# Why are there gaps on the right and left of linear layout?

Tags: android

I am learning android lately and this really bothers me.

[image]

Somehow the gap on the left and right can't be removed. I have tried changing the layout:margin right& left for the linear layout who owns all 4 buttons to "-10dp". However, that only stretches the selection box. For example, the number "9" got moved to  further left inside the button. It's like the button was indeed stretched but the stretched part was invisible or what.

This is probably a really stupid question but I can't seem to find an answer. Please help!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="example.org.bettercalculator.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="#89cf27">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background= "@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:paddingLeft="-20dp">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"></LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi  They are all 0. I have tried changing paddings to "-10" too but the same thing happened.

Comment: your xml files? It's honestly impossible to tell just from picture alone. On second thought, there is a way. Go to developer options in settings and click on "show layout bounds". That will show you how are your views rendered.

Comment: @poss I just added it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your releative layout has paddings on it. Because it's a parent ViewGroup, child views are rendered only in area with paddings.

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: I see! and what does "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" means? It was set automatically to "16dp" when I checked it

Comment: That's just something android likes to add as a default template value. Views shouldnt be right at the edge of display for both aesthetic reasons and misclick reasons. It's recommended to give some space between edge and content and that's why there is 16dp gap set as default.